# sregex_token_iterator: Stroustrup example has errata?

Tags: c++

I'm testing an example from Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Page 1069, which may have unlisted errata [here](https://www.stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html).  Does anyone know how this code should be modified to correctly print the output below?  The book claims this should be the output, however my test outputs nothing (no matches).

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input {"aa::bb cc::dd ee::ff"};
    regex pat {R"((\w+)([[:punct:]]+)(\w+)\s∗)"};
    sregex_token_iterator end {};
    for (sregex_token_iterator p {input.begin(),input.end(),pat,{1,3}};
     p!=end; ++p)
    cout << *p << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Book claims output should be:

```
aa 
bb 
cc 
dd 
ee 
ff
```

Compilation:

```
clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 -pedantic test248.cc && ./a.out

Compilation finished at Wed Aug  5 20:09:52
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    regex pat {R"((\w+)([[:punct:]]+)(\w+)\s∗)"};
```

Your "asterisk" at the end is not an actual `*` asterisk, but the Asterisk Operator Unicode character [U+2217](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2217/index.htm) instead. Replace it with a `*` and the code [will work](https://godbolt.org/z/n7Yda1).